# analyze and validate string and substring

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hello I want to select a subchain and analyze it example:

my chain to analyze

NADSU 78000mc0cl0Css

NADBY 7808810008659

PAT 1 21D 089

I need to read and then analyze line by line of a .txt file after that I would like to verify through an if or case cycle that the paramenters could be fulfilled. I clarify the txt file has about 300 lines

the first three characters must be letters with a specific format the following is usually the 4 character or 5 that has a number depends on that number means something and the last is the purchase order number or the amount or type of wrap ... ... this is a generalized idea I'm only giving the minimum to understand ...

Annex example and my code

I put two real cases of the line to analyze

--- here the letters nad = purchase order BY = supplier the remaining one is the purchase order number

NADBY 7808810008659

--- here Pat means = type of payment. the first number = the type of payment if it is one the type of payment is counted if it is two credits. the average 21d = number of days to issue clearance and the 089 = number of days to pay

PAT 1 21D 089

--- here the letters nad = purchase order BY = buyer css = a boxes but it can be ss = minicams

NADSU 78000mc0cl0Css

```html
fileopen ('nombre_doc.txt',r) do |fichero1| 

fileopen ('copianombre_doc.txt',w) do |fichero2| 

while linea= fichero1.gets 
 
fichero1=gsub(/\s+/,'')
```

Comment: I have the code in the encryption_controller.rb

Comment: yes I already saw and updated, I was overlooked, if you can help me, I would be thankful and wanted a lot and I did not get anything useful in my case